# amp form not submitting form data

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, amp-html

I have use case of a form with an autocomplete that reads json from a backend, and also a set of input fields inside the form reading from state. I'm trying to make the page work as follows:
1- user clicks inside the autocomplete
2- user types text
3- user selects item
4- once clicked, entire form gets submitted to the backend
5- user gets redirected to the respective page

Here's my current amp code:

```
                                    <form
                                            className="amp-search-areas-form"
                                            method="post"
                                            // action-xhr={`${hostName}/api/areas`}
                                            action-xhr="https://url/api/areas"
                                            target="_top"
                                            id="searchform"
                                            dir="rtl"
                                        >
                                            <div
                                                style={{
                                                    fontSize: 'large',
                                                    fontWeight: '600',
                                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    paddingBottom: '10px',
                                                    textAlign: 'right',
                                                }}
                                            >
enter area name
                                            </div>
                                            <amp-autocomplete
                                                filter="substring"
                                                filter-value="name"
                                                // src={`${hostName}/api/areas`}
                                                src="https://url/api/areas"
                                                on="select:AMP.setState({ defaultState: { area: event.value }}), searchform.submit"
                                                query="name"
                                                submit-on-enter="true"
                                                highlight-user-entry="true"
                                                items="items"
                                                // on="change:searchform.submit" //triggers submit on select
                                                // on="tap:search-lightbox.close,AMP.setState({ fullScreenLightBox: ['banner-search-panel'] })" //should close on change
                                            >
                                                <input
                                                    dir="rtl"
                                                    type="search"
                                                    name="selectedArea"
                                                    role="areasearch"
                                                    tabIndex="3"
                                                    className="amp-search-areas-input"
                                                    placeholder="placeholder"
                                                />
                                                <AmpMustache
                                                    template={`
                                                            <div data-value="{{name}}">
                                                                <div>{{ name }}</div>
                                                            </div>`}
                                                />
                                            </amp-autocomplete>
                                            <input
                                                name="typeField"
                                                type="text"
                                                // hidden
                                                data-amp-bind-value="defaultState.type"
                                            ></input>
                                            <input
                                                name="catField"
                                                type="text"
                                                // hidden
                                                data-amp-bind-value="defaultState.cat"
                                            ></input>
                                            <input
                                                name="areaField"
                                                type="text"
                                                // hidden
                                                data-amp-bind-value="defaultState.area"
                                            ></input>
                                        </form>
```

Of course I have imported all required amp components above the page, like form, bind, autocomplete, mustache, etc.

Here's my backend code:

```
exports.createSearchRedirect = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("exports.createSearchRedirect -> req.params", req.params)
        console.log("exports.createSearchRedirect -> req.query", req.query)
        console.log("exports.createSearchRedirect -> req.body", req.body)
        let generatedUrl = '';
        res.set(
            'AMP-Redirect-To',
            encodeURI('https://url/search/' + generatedUrl)
        );
        res.json(true);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('exports.createSearchRedirect -> error', error);
    }
};
```

My express config:

```
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  server.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've solved it by changing the default encoding type to                                            application/x-www-form-urlencoded

so my form now looks like this:

```
 <form
      className="amp-search-areas-form"
     method="post"
    action-xhr="url/api/areas"
     target="_top"
     id="searchform"
     dir="rtl"
     encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> // this line here 
        .
        .
        .
        etc
  </form>
```